# How to fetch prerequiste courses using connect by prior in oracle?

Tags: oracle

For the following  sample of table prerequisites:

```
**DEPT**  **COURSE** **PRE_DEPT** **PRE_COURSE**
   CS        532       CS             432
   CS        432       CS             332
   CS        552       CS             562
   CS        332       CS             232
```

Now I want to find prerequisites for course 532,I should get 432(direct prerequiste)
332 and 232(indirect prerequisite). Note: Here its 3 level it can be of any level.
How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  This question shows no effort on your part.

Comment: you can check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can try this demo code for your desired output, remember its in oracle :-

```
create table tdxd
(dept varchar2(4),course number,pre_dept varchar2(4),pre_course   number);

insert all 
into tdxd values ('CS',532,'CS',432)
into tdxd values  ('CS',432,'CS',332)
into tdxd values('CS',552,'CS',562)
into tdxd values('CS',332,'CS',232)
select * from dual;    

commit;

select course,pre_course,direct_prerequisite,
substr(indirect_prerequisite,instr(indirect_prerequisite,'>')+1)
dirct_to_indirct_prerequisite
from(
select  course,pre_course,connect_by_root pre_course direct_prerequisite,
sys_connect_by_path(pre_course,'>') as  indirect_prerequisite
from    tdxd
start   with course = 532
connect by prior pre_course = course);
```